# What happens to the voltage across an inductor as the frequency increases?

Tags: ac, inductor, transient

My professor told us before that when DC is passed through an inductor and reaches t = infinity the element becomes open. How does this happen?

By the way: the inductor has no charge at t = 0s.

Comment: Your title mentions frequency increasing, but your text asks about time going to infinitiy. Can you clarify which one you want to ask about?

Comment: "Open" as in a water valve i.e. passing water or, "short" as in the electrical sense that means the same?

Answer (score 4):

> My professor told us before that when dc current is passed thru an inductor and reaches t = infinity the element becomes open. How does this happen?

I'm surprised your professor didn't say the inductor becomes a **short** at \$t=\infty\$.

The formula describing an inductor is \$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}\$. So if the current isn't changing, the voltage across it goes to 0. In the circuit you described, the current (and every other variable in the circuit) tends to change more and more slowly as \$t\to\infty\$, and therefore the voltage across the inductor tends toward 0, which is similar to a **short** circuit, not an open.

Comment: Possibly he is expecting the conductor to melt before T=infinity...

Answer (score 2):

- No charge at t = 0
- Open-circuit at t = \$\inf\$

These are correct statements about a **capacitor** in an RC charging circuit. They do not apply to an inductor because:

- Inductors do not store charge.
- As [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/485174/244728) answer states, an inductor would behave as a short at t = \$\inf\$

As such, I believe your professor misspoke, and was actually referring to a capacitor.

To answer your question, the capacitor becomes an "open" circuit at t = \$\inf\$ because the charge stored in it generates a potential equal to the potential that is charging it. Thus there is no longer a potential difference in the circuit, and charge no longer flows.